# Multiple Forms in WinForm application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an application which has multiple forms, but I have to start one or other depending on the app.config key. So, first, when I start the app, I should read the config, and then, start one or other form. How can i do? Because on the Program.cs, I have to write in the Applicatio Run the name of the Form..
Thanks.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Mati, why don't you utilize a custom CONFIG.TXT (or any other file extension) to hold which form you must open?  Anyway, why don't you utilize Application.Settings?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, place below logic in `Main`. By default, `Main` resides in `program.cs`

```
 var formname = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["formname"].ToString();

 Application.EnableVisualStyles();
 Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
 Form form = formname.Equals("Form2") ? (Form) new Form2() : new Form1(); // play with whatever you want
 Application.Run(form);
```

Comment: I don't like people down voting without specifying the reason. It neither benefits you nor me.

Comment: After all answer can be improved with the suggestions or will help understanding what is right.

Comment: I suggest down voter reading this article [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes)

Comment: Very valid points and you will be ending up to everyone who downvotes the question without reason. How about forcing the downvoter to add comments by mandate like one cannot downvote without adding comment to the question raised?

Comment: @ArulManivannan Seriously, need that. Someone down vote either should add the comment or support other's comment (up voting comment).